# Unable to send front end data (AngularJS) to backend (Spring)

Tags: angularjs, spring

**Front-end:**

```
var req = {
    method : 'GET',
    url : 'http://171.10.13.24:8989/SpringMvcJdbcTemplate/editContact',
    headers : {
        'Content-Type' : undefined
    },
    params : {
        id : $scope.user.id
    }
}

$http(req).then(function(responce) {
    // success function
    alert("success");
}, function(responce) {
    // Failure Function
});
```

This is Angular code for send request.

**Back-end:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/editContact", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView editContact(HttpServletRequest request) {
    int contactId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
    Contact contact = contactDAO.get(contactId);
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("ContactForm");
    model.addObject("contact", contact);
    return model;
}
```

Comment: Its returns empty response

Comment: Why the content type is undefined? please show a screenshot of the error, I don´t see any question there.

Comment: Why are you using `ModelView`? Use `ResponseEntity` instead